# Collect the information entered in a form when "Next" is chosen after a section

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Is it possible to collect the information entered in a form when "Next" is chosen after a section? I have used `getResponses()` after form submission, but am curious if there is any case where "Next" is considered a submission?

I am looking to take the short answer input of a form, check to see if that short answer appears in a google sheet, and based on that, provide new questions in another section. This can be easily done in forms (without scripting) for multiple choice and drop down questions, but not so easily with short answers.

I am able to check the input after form submission, but as far as I can tell, there is no way to open the form up again after it is submitted to pose new questions.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: If you want this functionality, better to create your own form/webapp

Answer (score 1):

Apps script for Google Forms is basically limited to the form editor and post submission, so what you want is not possible. You can look at the [available triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) for more details.